# Module name clashes with exported type in Julia

Tags: module, julia

I happen to make a silly mistake - to create a type which has the name of the module it is in. Suppose that I want to export that type `X` from my package `X`:

```
module X

export X
export .X
export X.X

type X end

end
```

First would give me:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: invalid redefinition of constant X
```

Second:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: invalid identifier name "."
```

Third:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: extra token "." after end of expression
```

is there a valid syntax to solve my export problem?

P.S. I know that I could just change name for module/type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're screwed... :/  Convention is to pluralize the module name if it wraps a type of that name.

Comment: Thanks for the question and the commen from @TomBreloff. I didn't even notice that you're not supposed to give a module and a type the same name and I didn't understand the error message.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tom Breloff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5075246/tom-breloff) said, there is the well-followed practice for naming packages that implement a new type.  If your package exports a type that supports very fast operations on very small strings, and that type is named `FastString`, the recommended package name is `FastStrings.jl`.

Julia package names include the `.jl` suffix .. so should yours.  For projects that pull multiple packages together under one umbrella, the project name may forgo the trailing `.jl`; the packages it brings together should end with `.jl`.

[Some guidelines for naming packages are gathered here](https://github.com/JuliaPraxis/Naming/blob/master/guides/PackagesAndModules.md)